# Creating a rectangle on C using SDL

Tags: c, sdl

I'm trying to create a rectangle using SDL, however it does not compile. I have previously created a window screen and it works fine on the SDL compiler. Can you please check my code for any errors. An example will be helpful, thanks.

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    SDL_Window *p;
    SDL_Renderer *w;

    p = SDL_CreateWindow("Game",SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,800,640,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(w,255,0,0,255);
    SDL_Rect Rect = {220,140,200,200};
    SDL_RenderFillRect(w,&Rect);

    SDL_Delay(3000);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(p);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation output:

> 1> c: \ c lib \ sdl2-2.0.4 \ sdl2 tutorials \ sdl2 tutorials \ project 2.c (13): error C2275: 'SDL_Rect': this format was used in the wrong way.
>   1> c: \ c_lib \ sdl2-2.0.4 \ include \ sdl_rect.h (68): Refer to the 'SDL_Rect' declarations.
>   1> c: \ c_lib \ sdl2-2.0.4 \ sdl2_tutorials \ sdl2_tutorials \ project_2.c (13): error C2146: syntax error: ';' (s) 'Rect' not in front of the identifier.
>   1> c: \ c_lib \ sdl2-2.0.4 \ sdl2_tutorials \ sdl2_tutorials \ project_2.c (13): error C2065: 'Rect': undeclared identifier is.
>   1> c: \ c_lib \ sdl2-2.0.4 \ sdl2_tutorials \ sdl2_tutorials \ project_2.c (13): error C2059: syntax error: '{'
>   1> c: \ c_lib \ sdl2-2.0.4 \ sdl2_tutorials \ sdl2_tutorials \ project_2.c (14): error C2065: 'Rect': undeclared identifier is.
>   1> c: \ c_lib \ sdl2-2.0.4 \ sdl2_tutorials \ sdl2_tutorials \ project_2.c (14): warning C4133: 'function': 'int *' (on) 'const SDL_Rect *' This format is not compatible between not.
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, the latest 0, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Does it compile? Does it work on your machine? In case you want someone to review your code, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for that.

Comment: please post the compilation error you are getting

Comment: Which compiler is this? It looks like you've run its output through a machine translator, making the messages (more) confusing.

Answer (score 1):

SDL_Renderer was declared but but wasn't initialized and called in the program. I modified your code to initialize and call the renderer and it runs fine on my machine.
Code;

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    SDL_Window *p;
    SDL_Renderer *w;

    p = SDL_CreateWindow("Game",SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,800,640,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    // initialize the renderer
    w = SDL_CreateRenderer(p, -1, 0);
    // clear the renderer
    SDL_RenderClear(w);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(w,255,0,0,255);
    SDL_Rect Rect = {220,140,200,200};
    SDL_RenderFillRect(w,&Rect);

    // call the renderer   
    SDL_RenderPresent(w);

    SDL_Delay(3000);

    // destroy the renderer
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(w);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(p);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Hope that helps.